# Uninvolved Mat gets unexplainable overwritten during inRange

Tags: c++, opencv

If got a very strange problem here. Im developing with Visual Studio 10 and OpenCV
In the following code segment I'm creating a 1 channel Mat and write into two different Mats. 
First window "test1" shows a black picture. That's correct.

The "test2" window still shows a black picture. Still correct.

Then the last window "test3", shows the same picture as stored in bwHSVred after the inRange command.
Why would the bwHSVblue change during this inRange operation?

Does anybody know why? It doesn't make any sense to me a all.

```
frame = imread(pathtopicture);

cvtColor(frame, calHSV, COLOR_BGR2HSV);

inRange(calibHSV, Scalar(255, 255, 255), Scalar(0, 0, 0), bwAll);

bwHSVred = bwAll;
bwHSVblue = bwAll;
imshow("test1",bwHSVblue);

//load red
//set the x_MIN,x_MAX values to Hmin=0,Smin=119,Vmin=108,Hmax=218,Smax=234,Vmax=168
setHSVval(redCube);
updateTrackbars();
currentColor = RED;

imshow("test2",bwHSVblue);

inRange(calibHSV, Scalar(H_MIN, S_MIN, V_MIN), Scalar(H_MAX, S_MAX, V_MAX), bwHSVred);

imshow("test3",bwHSVblue);
```

Definition of the Mat objects in the .h-file

```
private:
Mat calHSV;
Mat bwAll;
Mat bwHSVred;
Mat bwHSVblue;
```

Comment: Please do not add "solved" to your question title. If one of the answers helped you to solve the problem, [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/220538) by clicking the check mark in the left margin. If none of the answers were useful and you figured out a solution of your own, post your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your C/C++ usage of pointers.

All three matrices are the same instance:

```
bwHSVred = bwAll;
bwHSVblue = bwAll;
```

You are copying the pointer, meaning that they now all point to the same matrix.

If you want to make copies of a matrix, you should use `clone` or `copyTo` [as explained in the docs](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/mat_the_basic_image_container/mat_the_basic_image_container.html):

```
Mat F = A.clone();
Mat G;
A.copyTo(G);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. that sounds reasonable. I had this thought, but i didn't took it serious.
I still need to learn the specifics of c++ :)

Thanks you very much

Answer (score 0):

Mat a=b; does a shallow copy only ( both point to the same data )

that's why bwHSVred == bwHSVblue == bwAll